# How to update the script coded in ioncube4 to ioncube 5.5.19

Tags: php, ioncube

I have a script given below coded in ioncube4 which does not run on ioncube 5.5.19 and getting below error.

Fatal error: The file /home3/teaonclick/public_html/hahi.in/wp-content/themes/FlatZon/includes/pixr-amazon.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 4 and cannot run under PHP 5.5. Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for either PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5. in Unknown on line 0

How to update the script to work with ioncube 5.5.19?
My site is running in a shared hosted service provider on linux OS

PHP version 5.5.19
MySQL version   5.5.35-cll

the content of the file where showing the issue isas below.

```
<?php //0046b
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader'))
{
    $__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));
    $__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');
    if(function_exists('dl'))
    {
        @dl($__ln);
    }
    if(function_exists('_il_exec'))
    {
        return _il_exec();
    }
    $__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;
    $__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));
    $__here=dirname(__FILE__);
    if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':')
    {
        $__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));
        $__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));
    }
    $__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';
    $__i=strlen($__rd);
    while($__i--)
    {
        if($__rd[$__i]=='/')
        {
            $__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;
            if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp))
            {
                $__ln=$__lp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(function_exists('dl'))
    {
        @dl($__ln);
    }
}
else
{
    die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");
}
if(function_exists('_il_exec'))
{
    return _il_exec();
}
echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');
exit(199);

?>
HR+cPys/ztCE+Cj4mwPYK311udCFJfWF/McNVEDiA5pwzY1QSOjWWm4Rn1HE0AjyMFyv4qsiACbP
```

etc..

Answer (score 1):

The message comes because the internals of PHP are so different when comparing PHP 4 to PHP 5.5 that it is not possible to have complete compatibility when running scripts compiled for PHP 4 on PHP 5.5. This is therefore unsupported.

If the original provider of the scripts provides a version built for PHP 5 (though preferably for 5.4 or 5.5) then you can run it on PHP 5.5 or 5.6. Alternatively, use PHP 5.4 to run the old code. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.